# Django admin form dynamically change fields based on checkbox

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am implementing a calendar in Django and wanted to extend my functionality and add support for recurring events. My issue is I would like to have a BooleanField that toggles between single/multi-day events and recurring events. So the field would be labelled something like: Is this a recurring event? and if the user checks the box, it changes the start and end fields to display a different field.

Here is a brief version of my model.py

```
class Event(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    is_recurring = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False, verbose_name='Event is recurring?')

    start = models.DateTimeField()

    end = models.DateTimeField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And if the user checks the is_recurring field then dynamically remove those 2 fields and change the form. Here is my admin.py:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventForm
    fieldsets = [
        (None,  {'fields': [
                                'title',
                                'description'
                            ]
                }
        ),
        (None,  {'fields':  [
                                'is_recurring',
                                'start',
                                'end',
                            ]
                }
        ),
    ]   # END fieldset

    def get_fieldsets(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return(
                (None, {
                        'fields' : ('my_extra_field',),
                    }),
            )

admin.site.register(Event , EventAdmin)
```

and here is my forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_extra_field'] = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

So here I was trying to add `my_extra_field` to the form, to try it out, but I keep getting

> Unknown field(s) (my_extra_field) specified for Event. Check
>   fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class EventAdmin.

and cant find a way to retrieve my field. I have an impression it might be because I'm using a `fieldsets` and you might want to suggest not using it, but unfortunately there is alot of info that I removed from my model to make it more appropriate for a question and therefore I need to use `fieldsets`.

So to finalise my question, I'm wondering how to dynamically add a field base on my check box? and as an extension to the question, how to remove 2 fields from my form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra field must exist on the form so you can use it in your fieldsets:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_extra_field = forms.CharField()   

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = tuple()  # Required in recent Django versions.
                           # Be careful not to include fields by accident.
```

You will probably have to override `save()` on your form, since `ModelForm` does not know what to do with your extra fields.

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_extra_field = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cleaned_data['is_recurring']:
            # do something with your extra fields,
            # remove values from other fields, etc.
        super(EventForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to change your form without a page reload, you need to use Javascript.